# Select users that do have certain roles and do not have others

Tags: 7, users

I need some help with my SQL in that I want to get all users with a certain role that do have another role.

```
SELECT distinct users.uid, users.name, users.mail
FROM users AS users, users_roles AS ur
WHERE ur.uid = users.uid
AND ur.rid <> 4 
AND ur.rid = 13
```

My SQL is really bad so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your title contradicts your question content, NOT or not NOT?

Comment: I'm not sure that you are commenting because your understanding of my use of English is confusing you (1) or whether you are being extra specially pedantic (2).

If 1 then a further explanation of the title is I want users with a certain role that do not have another certain role.

if 2 then I'm not sure I can help you.

Comment: if you want use drupal API I provide answer for you and if you want only mysql code tell me

Comment: Yes I am confused, because of YOUR English: your title says NOT, your question details ask for the opposite, so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Drupal db_select API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) Use this to fetch user id and names that user have `roleId` 13 and not have `roleId` 14

```
$query = db_select('user', 'u');
$query->join('role', 'ur', 'u.uid = ur.uid'); 
$query->fields('u',array('uid','name'))
 ->condition('ur.rid', 13)
 ->condition('ur.rid', 14,'<>');
 $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
dpm($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out how to do the SQL. I used an 'anti-join'!! (a new one on me)

eg.

```
SELECT users.name, users.mail from 
users, users_roles as ur1
where
ur1.uid = users.uid
AND
ur1.rid =  13 
AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM users_roles ur2
WHERE ur1.uid = ur2.uid
AND sur2.rid = 4)
```

Same result as using the api just using SQL.

Comment: but my friend if you looking for only mysql query here is not suitable place, you should ask it in stackecxchange.com and if you need drupal solution  we provide it for you.